# Control over random value

Tags: c#, list, random

I use a random for browse list I do like this:

```
var oServer = new SmtpServer("");
var random = new Random();
var randomIndex = random.Next(list.Count());
var socks = list[randomIndex];

oServer.SocksProxyServer = socks.IpAddress.ToString();
oServer.SocksProxyPort = socks.Port;
```

I want that if value selected, will be not selected again in next. I want that it choose another value.

What I should do?

Comment: remove the item from the list?

Comment: i cant remove the item , i need the value

Comment: In that case make a new list when you've created `list` by: `indexList = Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count).ToList()` and use that to get the indices to use (and remove items from `indexList` instead).

Comment: @Matthew Watson can you give me this in answer i think that you answer is good

Comment: Dmitry Bychenko posted the same thing as an answer as I was posting that, so I think his is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *can't remove* from `list` itself, remove from `possibleIndexes`:

```
private static random = new Random();

...
List<int> possibleIndexes = Enumerable
  .Range(0, list.Count())
  .ToList();

...

int idx = random.Next(possibleIndexes.Count());
int index = possibleIndexes[idx];
possibleIndexes.RemoveAt(idx);
var socks = list[index];
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the item from the list if you don't want to use it again:

```
var socks = list[randomIndex];
list.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
```

Comment: @FatiFleur you should have mentioned that in your question then

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to lose data in orginal list first copy the list to another one then remove item from your copy list

```
        var copyList=new List<yourListType>();
        copyList.AddRange(list);//copy form your orginal list
        var socks = copyList[randomIndex];
        copyList.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
```

Or you can generate unique random number

```
     List<int> randomNumbers = new List<int>(list.Count());

        do
        {
            randomIndex = random.Next();
        } while (randomNumbers.Contains(randomIndex));

        randomNumbers.Add(randomIndex);
        var socks = list[randomIndex];
```